# How do I know/ sense that multithreading is helpful to my program

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I have a large one-thread java program which takes long time before outputting the result. I am considering make it concurrent but this made me wonder: is concurrency helpful to my application? Is it really going to help?

Thus, I am asking here:

> Which properties I should look for (*in my program*) in order to say
>   that multithreading/concurrency is the way to go?

Is there any rule-of-thump to this?

Comment: Approach this question from the other end.  Outline your app design, code AND DATA, then we could much more easily judge if, and where, some extra threads may be advantageous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multithreading should be used whenever your program can be broken down into multiple parallel executable tasks which are independent of each other.
for example,

```
int main() {

for (i=0;i<5;i++)
   fprintf("this is for task1")  // consider this function is writing data to file for task1

for (i=0;i<5;i++)
   fprintf("this is for task2")  // consider this function is writing data to file for task2

return 0;
}
```

Here we can see that writing to a file1 and file2 can be done in parallel as they are completely independent of each other. Thus multithreading can be used here to run both tasks simultaneously.

But before multithreading you should consider some things,

1. Do you really need it? Will that hamper your application logic?
2. can you improve it without multithreading?

   In above code we can do some improvement without using multithreading,

   int main() {

   ```
   for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
      fprintf("this is for task1")
      fprintf("this is for task2")  
   }
   ```

   return 0;
   }

here we can avoid second loop which is not required. here we cant avoid serial file writing but we got some improvement than previous (Do not think more about it, this is just an example :) )

3. Multithreading will only help if you have multiple cores on your CPU else though you use multithreading, results will be similar to serial code execution.

Hope you are clear now :)

Answer (score 2):

Good day,

Concurrency can usually be helpful to increase the speed at which an algorithm completes, granted that the algorithm must inherently then be viable for multi threading.

By viable for multi threading I mean that some parts of the algorithm should be able to be broken into separate parts that do not rely on a result of a sequential process. For instance if you have a loop that produces some result each time it is run, but does not require the previous iterations result then you could create multiple threads and run each one once instead of a loop. This will increase the speed at which the algorithm is completed.

The best measure then of effectiveness is the completion time.

Answer (score 1):

Find the tasks in your application which you think can be executed concurrently, then execute these tasks by multiple threads.

Comment: Begging won' t help, most probably. Write good answers and they will get votes.

Comment: @Fildor reason for downvoting? Answer is not up to mark, but not wrong.

Comment: I did not downvote. But I guess whoever did, it was for the reason of begging for upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to that is very subjective. If you need to process input in a synchronous manner, then concurrency would not be applicable. However, if you have a process that services multiple requests at a time, this would be a good application for it.

For example, the Servlet API is multi-threaded due to its highly concurrent nature - it has to service numerous independent requests in parallel. If you have a recurring process that runs asynchronous to your main application thread, for example a process to poll for new data every 5 minutes, this would also be a good use. However, if it is a user-initiated process that should block until it is completed, then there would be no value in spawning a separate thread.

Instead of asking "should I implement concurrency?", you should ask "how would this benefit from concurrency?" You can add concurrency to almost anything that you want, but the trick is in being able to determine on a case-by-case basis whether running a task asynchronously / concurrently provides any benefit.